# React Docker image working on local machine but when I move it to server gives Hooks error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, linux, docker, react-hooks

I have created a React and Node app and I containerized it in Docker an put it on a Linux server.

It worked fine till now (I added a pdf download functionality). On localhost it works fine, from Docker image on localhost same it works fine but when I upload it to the Linux server it gives me this error:

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This 
could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
▶ 20 stack frames were collapsed.
Module.<anonymous>
src/app/src/index.js:10
7 | import 'bootstrap-css-only/css/bootstrap.min.css';
8 | import 'mdbreact/dist/css/mdb.css';
9 | 
> 10 | ReactDOM.render(
11 |   <React.StrictMode>
12 |     <App />
13 |   </React.StrictMode>,
```

I do not know what to do. I checked the react and react-dom versions and they match 17.0.1 both of them.

And I do not understand why it works on localhost without any error and on the Linux machine it doesn`t work. I tried deleting with docker rmi the image and loading it again and I get the same error.

Dockerfile for React:

```
FROM node:lts-slim

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Dockerfile for Node:

```
FROM node:lts-slim

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 5000

# You can change this
CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

Docker-compose.yml file for building both images:

```
version: "3"
services:
frontend:
    container_name: awesome_web
    build:
        context: ./client
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: vikasraj/awesome_web
    ports:
        - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
        - ./client:/usr/src/app
backend:
    container_name: awesome_server
    build:
        context: ./server
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: vikasraj/awesome_server
    ports:
        - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
        - ./server:/usr/src/app
```

Package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
  "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
  "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
  "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
  "axios": "^0.21.1",
  "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
  "datatables": "^1.10.18",
  "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.24",
  "jquery": "^3.6.0",
  "jspdf": "^2.3.1",
  "mdbreact": "^5.0.1",
  "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
  "react": "^17.0.1",
  "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
  "react-responsive-data-table": "^1.0.5",
  "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
  "react-super-responsive-table": "^5.2.0",
  "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
   },
  "proxy": "http://backend:5000",
  "eslintConfig": {
  "extends": [
  "react-app",
  "react-app/jest"
   ]
   },
  "browserslist": {
  "production": [
  ">0.2%",
  "not dead",
  "not op_mini all"
   ],
  "development": [
  "last 1 chrome version",
  "last 1 firefox version",
  "last 1 safari version"
   ]
   }
   }
```

index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css';
import 'bootstrap-css-only/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'mdbreact/dist/css/mdb.css';

ReactDOM.render(
<React.StrictMode>
<App />
</React.StrictMode>,
document.getElementById('root')
);


reportWebVitals();
```

I have 2 containers one for React one for Node. I start them with:

```
docker run -d -p 3100:3000 reactcontainername
docker run -d -p 5100:5000 nodecontainername
```

Comment: Can we see your dockerfile, and maybe the package.json and index.js? Also, how are you starting the container? I ask because what you're describing doesn't make sense and we need more info to try to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I added all you asked

Comment: Because of the `volumes:`, you're running the code and library stack you've manually copied to the target system, and not the tested code built into the image.  Can you delete the `volumes:`, push the built images to some Docker registry, and then launch the containers on the deployment system without separately copying the source code?

Comment: Ideally we'd need to see your full repository for this - your error claims that you are making an invalid hook call, but we can't see the hooks you're calling. The best way to get help is to either share your repo on Github, or if that's not possible then try and create a minimal reproduction. Not only will this allow others to test it, it'll help you narrow down to the more specific parts of your code that may be causing this.